# if not count===0, I want the background of my notificiation box to turn red...how do I do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

So if (count == 0)
 {I want no effect on notification box} 
else 
{I want notification box to turn red} 
so this is what I did, but it doesn't work. by doesn't work I mean nothing happens, I checked css through inspect element but nothing is there...

```
      <style>
          {% block style %}
        #notification_dropdown.notification { background: red; }
        {% endblock %}
          </style>
    <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle notification-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-inbox' aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id='notification_dropdown'>

                  </ul>
                </li>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".notification-toggle").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "{% url 'get_notifications_ajax' %}",
              data: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
              },
             success: function(data){
                $("#notification_dropdown").html(' <li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">Notifications</li>');
                var count = data.count
                console.log(count)
                if (count == 0) {
                      $("#notification_dropdown").removeClass('notification');
                  var url = '{% url "notifications_all" %}'
                  $("#notification_dropdown").append("<li><a href='" + url+ "'>View All Notifications</a></li>")
                } else {
                      $("#notification_dropdown").addClass('notification');
                  $(data.notifications).each(function(){
                    var link = this;
                    $("#notification_dropdown").append("<li>" + link + "</li>")
                  })
                }
                console.log(data.notifications);
              },
              error: function(rs, e) {
                console.log(rs);
                console.log(e);
              }
            })
          })
        })
        </script>
```

I added  `$("#notification_dropdown").removeClass('notification');`

and                   `$("#notification_dropdown").addClass('notification');`
 after if and else.

and then I use css...
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is hard to say as your code is not executable as is. You should write a reduced example (and try it first).
Have you checked that `$("#notification_dropdown")` returns what you expect?
BTW, you should also "save" your query for efficiency matter: `myQ = $("#notification_dropdown");`

Comment: @MathieuCoquerelle yeah I did check that /i get <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="notification_dropdown">
                
              </ul>

Comment: @MathieuCoquerelle save what?...not good with js

Comment: See my answer below ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimalized example to answer your question:
HTML with your element and a button to trigger/test the JS code:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id='notification_dropdown'>
Notification text
</ul>

<a href="#" id="button">Button</a>
```

CSS:

```
#notification_dropdown{
  background-color: green;
}

#notification_dropdown.notification{
  background-color: red;
}
```

and the JavaScript code:

```
myButton = $("#button");

count = 0;

myButton.click( function() {
  myQuery = $("#notification_dropdown");
  console.log( count );

  if( count == 0 )
  {
    myQuery.removeClass( "notification" );
  }
  else
  {
    myQuery.addClass( "notification" );
  }

  // This is done just for the test matter
  count++; 
});
```

Simply click multiple times on the Button to trigger the associated `click` function which also changes `count` (for testing purpose).
The JQuery is save in the variable `myQuery` in order to avoid realizing the same query multiple times for no clear purpose.

[Try is on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ba50wkmr/)

Comment: hello thanks for the reply. what's button? I'm assuming it's <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-inbox' aria-hidden="true"></span>
 in my case?

Comment: The `button` id is simply used to have a clickable element in the case of my example (so I can trigger the function that changes the class).
So I guess that on your code it should relate somehow to the div of `class="dropdown-toggle notification-toggle"`.

Comment: thanks for the reply../I've been struggling with this one all day...so I shoudn't have click right?instead of butoton I should put dropdown-toggle?